# Ext Js proxy pass parameter

Tags: javascript, extjs, proxy, store, sencha-architect

I want to pass a parameter to my Store proxy to retrieve the right data from the server. I need to pass the parameter without the name prefix and just the value.

Instead of this kind of url :

```
myAppUrl/collections/units?collectionId=54
```

which can be done like this:

```
myStore.getProxy().extraParams.collectionId = 54;
```

I want to have a call like this:

```
myAppUrl/collections/54/units
```

My web service is adapted for both calls I just need the correct client code to pass the parameter.

Please help and advise.

Comment: Can you review the answers? :) Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

An old question, but I write for anyone with this problem. I implemented the idea of @Saki in this package (for ExtJS 6) because of my own needs:

https://bitbucket.org/alfonsonishikawa/extjspackages/wiki/Server%20URL%20Placeholders

The idea is being able to use an URL like:

```
proxy: {
  type: 'rest',
  url: 'myAppUrl/collections/${collectionId}/units',
  appendId: false
}
```

With that package, you just have to configure your proxy like above and call `#load()` with params:

```
store.load({
  params: {
      collectionId: 54
  }
});
```

(`getProxy().extraParams` can be used as default value)

[This is the source code](https://bitbucket.org/alfonsonishikawa/extjspackages/src/31740fae8d75190ece7494e4d5986f20dae3d841/packages/local/nishilua-server-url-placeholders/overrides/data/proxy/?at=master) as example that you asked @Saki about.

Answer (score 1):

It looks almost like REST request but not exactly as REST places indexes at the end of url. You could solve it by implementing a custom [`buildUrl`](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Ajax-method-buildUrl) of Ajax or Rest proxy. In any case, see how is this method implemented in Rest proxy.

Comment: Could you provide a simple example

Comment: I haven't (yet) had the requirement of a custom URL such as yours so I don't have any working example I could share with you. The thing is simpler than it looks: You get the request as argument and you return ready made url. The logic in between is also going to be quite simple.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, helped me to create the package :)

Answer (score 0):

you can set your url dynamically and then call load method of store using below code.

```
store.getProxy().setUrl('your new url');
store.load();
```

but if you gonna use this method then you have to set correct url every time other-vice may be you will get wrong data.